# the database cannot be opened (visual studio 2015)

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2015

I have a project (c# windows forms). I was working on it on my friend's computer, Now I'm obliged to continue working on this project on my own computer.
so I copied the project in my machine and when I tried to add the database this message appears ..

> The database cannot be opened because it is version 852, this server supports version 782 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported .....

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to open a database newer than the engine in which you are trying to restore. If you have access to the original database environment, script the whole database and then you can restore it on your database engine.

You can try changing the compatibility of the database on your friend PC to 782 in which your system seems to work OK. You can try that running this script:

```
ALTER DATABASE YourDBName  
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 120;  
GO
```

In this article you can see the SQL and VS database version numbers:

http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com.ar/2014/01/sql-server-internal-database-versions.html

Comment: I have just the .mdf file of the data base (database.mdf) ..

Comment: You can use the ATTACH DATABASE statement to set this compatibility as well.